# Compute the color of a specific point on a two-dimensional angled linear gradient

Tags: javascript, math, interpolation, gradient, linear-gradients

I need to calculate the color of a pixel on a linear gradient with specified width, length, starting and ending colors, and at a specific angle.

After days of research and trying to understand the mechanics of this, along with some AI help (who by the way did not produce a working result after more than 30 revisions), i came up with this approach:

```
function getColorAtCoordinate(x, y, width, height, angle, startColor, endColor) {

   // angle to radians
  const angleRad = (angle * Math.PI) / 180; 

   // get diagonal length of rectangle
  const diagonalLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2)); 

   // calculate distance from start (top-left) of rectangle
  const distanceFromStart = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));

   // calculate distance from end (bottom-right corner) of rectangle
  const distanceFromEnd = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - width, 2) + Math.pow(y - height, 2)); 

   // calculate position of point between start and end of gradient
  const position = distanceFromStart / (distanceFromStart + distanceFromEnd); 

   // calculate color components
  const red = Math.round(startColor.r + (endColor.r - startColor.r) * position);
  const green = Math.round(startColor.g + (endColor.g - startColor.g) * position);
  const blue = Math.round(startColor.b + (endColor.b - startColor.b) * position);

   // return string
  return "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";

}
```

The problem is that the function seems to not correctly take into account the angle.

To test it, i wrote a little function that draws a gradient onto a canvas pixel by pixel, using the `getColorAtCoordinate` function.

I provide a snippet and a [link to a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hbLy9r7/1/).

I am drawing two canvas elements with the same colors and dimensions, but with differing angles (0 and 135 respectively). As you can see, both canvas elements turn out exactly the same. I tried to figure out why, and i think it's because the distances from the start and end points are incorrectly calculated for angles other than 0 or 180 degrees.

Mathematics isn't my strong suit. Maybe someone can enlighten me.

```js
function getColorAtCoordinate(x, y, width, height, angle, startColor, endColor) {
  const angleRad = (angle * Math.PI) / 180;
  const diagonalLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
  const distanceFromStart = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
  const distanceFromEnd = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - width, 2) + Math.pow(y - height, 2));
  const position = distanceFromStart / (distanceFromStart + distanceFromEnd);
  const red = Math.round(startColor.r + (endColor.r - startColor.r) * position);
  const green = Math.round(startColor.g + (endColor.g - startColor.g) * position);
  const blue = Math.round(startColor.b + (endColor.b - startColor.b) * position);
  return "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
}         

function drawGradientCanvas(width, height, angle, startColor, endColor) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      const color = getColorAtCoordinate(x, y, width, height, angle, startColor, endColor);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  });
}

drawGradientCanvas(1057,404,0,{r:87,g:154,b:209},{r:31,g:103,b:157});
drawGradientCanvas(1057,404,135,{r:87,g:154,b:209},{r:31,g:103,b:157});
```

Comment: Your function getColorAtCoordinate() doesn't use angle at all except to calculate angleRad which it doesn't use either. What is angle measured from? Does a zero angle mean the vertical colours are constant or the horizontal colours? Could you supply some expected output of the function at say getColorAtCoordinate(200, 300, 1057, 404, 30, {r:87,g:154,b:209},{r:31,g:103,b:157}). You appear to be struggling with this as you submitted a virtually identical question recently no?

Comment: Yeah, i've been at this for days. Can't think straight anymore, apparently. The zero angle would mean vertical colors are constant, as it is a linear gradient. I deleted my former question as i had made progress since then, and it seemed badly formulated and lost its momentum. The output for your example values would be rgb(71,139,194)

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be trickier than I anticipated. The following function is a guide only. You'll need to do some error checking to ensure the outputs don't go out of range and decide what to do to avoid a division by zero etc.

```
function getColorAtCoordinate(x, y, width, height, angle, startColor, endColor) {
  const angleRad = (angle * Math.PI) / 180;
  const sinangle = Math.sin(angleRad);
  const cosangle = Math.cos(angleRad);
  const D = width * cosangle + height * sinangle;
  const s = x * cosangle + y * sinangle;  
  const colorgradr = (endColor.r - startColor.r)/D;
  const red = Math.round(startColor.r + s*colorgradr);
  const colorgradg = (endColor.g - startColor.g)/D;
  const green = Math.round(startColor.g + s*colorgradg);
  const colorgradb = (endColor.b - startColor.b)/D;
  const blue = Math.round(startColor.b + s*colorgradb);
  return "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
}
```

I tested the expected output you gave me in the jsfiddle link but for some reason the gradient doesn't appear in the graphics. There must be some issue with the other part of the code. I'm better at maths than Javascript so I'll leave you to figure out the rest.

```
getColorAtCoordinate(200, 300, 1057, 404, 30, {r:87,g:154,b:209},{r:31,g:103,b:157}) = rgb(71, 139, 194)
```